# Using switch to trigger commands

Tags: powershell

Seem to be figuring it out quite quickly though!

So basically I'm modifying a script to help us speed the employee joining process, ill have a few questions, but my first is trying to get the user account mail enabled in exchange after its created.
Ive put some options in there so our guys can choose which exchange database the account should be created on. What i cant work out is how to do it properly. (not sure on the correct syntax)

Originally i tried using a variable and passing the input to that, but that didn't seem to work as the variable didn't get picked up, so I'm now trying the below way

I know I've not written the below expressions correctly, as they error - so want to know how i should correctly write the below

```
switch ($result) {
    1 { $database = "Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\$un -Database Database1" } 
    2 { $database = "Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\$un -Database Database2" } 
    3 { $database = "Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\$un -Database Database3" } 
}
```

Help very much appreciated :)

Comment: Please rename your question. How is "Very new to power shell" describing your problem?

Comment: Also, if there is an error, *provide the error message in your question*.  Simply copy it out of powershell and add it to an [edit] <= LOOK, it's clickable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say simply remove the quotes around your commands, now they're only strings:

```
switch ($result) {
    1 { $database = Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\$un -Database Database1 }
    2 { $database = Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\$un -Database Database2 }
    3 { $database = Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\$un -Database Database3 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Fairly obvious! Working now :)

Comment: @Eddie welcome ! Vote up the answers you like, accept (green checkmark near the votes) the one you prefer. Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation in situations like this is to separate the **data** from the **code**, as this makes maintenance far more simple later on.  It also enables you to re-use the data.  In this instance, I'd create a hash table, 
e.g.:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2;

[Int32]     $Local:intHashKey          = 0;
[Int32]     $Local:intSelection        = 0;
[String]    $Local:strDatabase         = '';
[Hashtable] $Local:objExchangeDBLookup = @{ 1 = 'Database1';
                                            2 = 'Database2';
                                            3 = 'Database3'
                                          };
# Display options and get selection.
do {
    Foreach ( $intHashKey in ($objExchangeDBLookup.Keys | Sort-Object) ) { 
        Write-Host -Object ( '{0}. {1}' -f $intHashKey, $objExchangeDBLookup[$intHashKey] );
        } #Foreach
    $intSelection = Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease select a database";
    } until ( $objExchangeDBLookup.ContainsKey( $intSelection ) );

# Create Mailbox.
try {
    $strDatabase = $objExchangeDBLookup[$intSelection];
    Write-Host -Object ( 'Creating mailbox on DB "{0}"...' -f $strDatabase );
    Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\$un -Database $strDatabase;
    } #try
catch [System.Exception] {
    # Something went wrong.
    } #catch
```

The code is quit verbose and deliberately uses static data types for hardening purposes.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! This is obviously more complicated and something I'm not sure i can get my head around at the moment! :) - Ive got my script working mostly so may need a bit more advice :)

Comment: @Eddie you should try and understand this piece of code, this will push you forward for sure : )